# CRUD Operation in WPF using Data Sets / ADO.Net

Tags: wpf, set, crud

I am learning WPF. For this purpose i am creating a desktop application. Please consider following code:

```
private void New_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WpfApplication12.TestDataSet testDataSet = ((WpfApplication12.TestDataSet)(this.FindResource("testDataSet")));


    TestDataSet.CustomersRow custrow;
    custrow = testDataSet.Customers[0];

    custrow = testDataSet.Customers.NewCustomersRow();
}

private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WpfApplication12.TestDataSet testDataSet = ((WpfApplication12.TestDataSet)(this.FindResource("testDataSet")));
    TestDataSet.CustomersRow custrow;
    custrow = testDataSet.Customers[0];

    custrow.EndEdit();
    custrow.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Now the problem is, instead of inserting new record, it edits the current record. Please help.
Also view wpf form here :

[image]